# Shorter way to check multiple or conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there any easier way of checking one variables value against several others? Currently I'm using code like this:

```
if(a[i] == a[i-13] || a[i] == a[i+13] || a[i] == a[i-1] || a[i] == a[i+1]){
  //my code
}
```

Now, is there a shorter way to do this? I know I can use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), but then I'd have to write my function several times. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to write your function several times with a switch:

```
switch(a[i]){
  case a[i-13]:
  case a[i+13]:
  case a[i-1]:
  case a[i+1]:
    // This code will run if any of the above cases are true.
}
```

*Amusingly, however, this is just about the same number of characters (depending on how you format it). A switch statement in general is less powerful than an explicit `if` statement, but in this case I find it clearer and less error-prone.*

Answer (score 2):

And better yet:

```
if (matchesAdjacent(a, i)) {
    // etc.
}
```

Move the logic out of the mainline code into an appropriately-named method.

This also lets you do your bounds checking there (if it isn't already guaranteed elsewhere).

Comment: It probably would have to be `matchesAdjacent(a, i)`.

Answer (score 1):

No. However the following looks neater:

```
if(a[i] == a[i-13] || 
   a[i] == a[i+13] || 
   a[i] == a[i-1] || 
   a[i] == a[i+1]
) {
  //my code
}
```